# PHP /MYSQL Variable inside Longtext data

Tags: php, mysql

How possible is this?

Say a longtext data with variable saved in it.

The actual data in a longtext mysql database in a field called "description".

```
"The date today is :" . $data_var . "."
```

in PHP:

```
$data_var = date('Y/m/d'); 
echo  $row['description'];
```

output should be:

```
The date today is : 2012/10/02.
```

Please advise.

Comment: Another, but not recommended function is [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: `eval()` is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in database are not parsed as variable, use `str_replace()`:

```
$data_var = date('Y/m/d'); 
echo str_replace('$data_var', $data_var, $row['description']);
```

or in your case:

```
echo str_replace('" . $data_var . "', $data_var, $row['description']);
```

Try not to insert variables in database!

Answer (score 1):

i think you should analyze why you need to do that and should redesign your application so that you don't have to. you should try your best to separate your data from your application logic and what you are trying to achieve is to store application logic in the db.